# Dialpad is missing in android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

For some reason Dialpad/ dial button is missing from the android emulator. In fact there is no dialer app as well in the emulator. In `AVD Details` I can see `hw.Dpad:yes`. I want to call from one emulator instance to another for testing purpose. What is the issue here ?